# How to get all HTML form data and save it in a pdf format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Suppose we have field as first name and last name in an html page. And we want to get the values of these and save it in a pdf file with the click of a button or link.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.myForm input[type=submit]').click(function(){
   var val1 = $('#field1').val();
   //your logic
});
```

You logic depends on your strategy of creating pdf. You could either do an ajax call and post the form data on your server where you create pdf using a server side programming language or you try a javascript pdf framework.

E.g. http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

See this demo http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

Comment: I am using html 5 and the data need to be dispalyed in a pdf file. No server side callingis required and also it need to be done without servlets.

Comment: Well then my examples just suit your case ;)

Comment: with the help of this i am getting a dialog box but i want to fetch only data in text box or radio buttons